# Insert csv file into mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to load a huge amount of data from a CSV file. I wrote this program to do it but when I execute the program it shows me an error. The error is:

> file not found

If I `echo` the query then the file path that is shown is different than the mysql search for the file.

```
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"] ["tmp_name"];

    // Creating a temporary table to hold csv file data....
    $tmp_tbl = "CREATE TABLE track LIKE trackingsite";

    mysqli_query($this->conn, $tmp_tbl) or die( "Temporary table creation failed: " . mysqli_error($this->conn) );

    $file_load = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$fileName' INTO TABLE track FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ";
    echo $file_load;

    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    mysqli_query($this->conn, $file_load) or die( "Can not insert data: " . mysqli_error($this->conn) );
```

Comment: Where is the file? Do you try to upload it with a HTML form, or is it already on the server?

Comment: I have the html form i only give here the php code that has error, the problem is actually in the file path.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use absoulute directly path to load the file.

Like 'for exmaple "C://xammp/htdoc" in  $fileName

Comment: Actually I have to load the file from different path at different time so I like to use it dynamically and this code can read the file data perfectly but can't insert data into database